# What are some potential reasons that ngOnInit() is not being invoked immediately within a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript

A child component within my project is not having its ngOnInit() method being called upon initialization but I do not have any errors within the project. I am wondering if this could be due to incorrect declarations in the .module or something else. If anyone could offer solutions or resources for better understanding how ngOnInit() is invoked I'd appreciate it.

I tried looking through the .modules which import and export certain components.

Comment: Is the component marked to implement the interface? `export class MyComponent implements OnInit`? Please add your code so we can better identify the problem.

Comment: How you expect having help if you didn't posted a sample code? Please provide a example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.